# Replacing characters in an array with numbers

Tags: r, arrays, for-loop, variables, apply

I have read in data from an excel file, and made it into a vector.
I then made it into a 3d array.

The vector that forms the array, and also inside the array now has in it characters, like this:

```
D <- c('g', 't', NA, 'd')
nPeriods = 3
column.names = c('aaa', 'bbb')
row.names = c('jjj', 'hhh')
threeD.names = c(1:nPeriods)
E = array(c(D), dim=c(2, 2, nPeriods),
          dimnames = list(row.names, column.names, threeD.names))
```

However, now I want to assign 'g', 't', etc as variables with starting values, e.g.

```
g = 5
t = 2
d = 7
```

But the only way I know how to do this is by manually figuring out which element of the array it is and assigning it like that, e.g.

```
E[1,1,]=5
```

When it's a large matrix that's going to be difficult and annoying to find the corresponding position every time I refer to an element. I know that each element of the vector (that is not NA) is unique, so I wondered, is there a shortcut for referring to each element of the array? (Maybe something in the apply family? but there are so many of them).

I will also need to refer later to them to loop over nPeriods. Yesterday someone showed me I can do this with:

```
for (i in 2:nPeriods){
  C[1,1,i]=C[1,1,i-1]*2
}
```

But in real life my matrix might be quite large so I'd rather just be able to refer with d, t, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store your replacement values in a named vector, you can then use `apply` to replace elements by name. `apply` handles the looping automatically, and even converts the result to a numeric array if all non-NA elements are numeric. Note that the `1:3` in the `apply` call refers to the three dimensions of your array, not the length of the third dimension, so this should work no matter how large the array is.

```
values <- c(g = 5,
            t = 2,
            d = 7)

num_array <- apply(E, 1:3, function(x) values[x])

num_array

, , 1

    aaa bbb
jjj   5  NA
hhh   2   7

, , 2

    aaa bbb
jjj   5  NA
hhh   2   7

, , 3

    aaa bbb
jjj   5  NA
hhh   2   7
```

Your second question is unclear, but you can `which` to get the elements efficiently. You only need to loop over the slices:

```
result <- num_array
for (i in 2:dim(num_array)[3]) {
  idx <- which(E[, , 1] == 'g', arr.ind = T)
  row <- idx[1, 'row']
  col <- idx[1, 'col']
  result[row, col, i] <- result[row, col, i-1] * 2
}

, , 1

    aaa bbb
jjj   5  NA
hhh   2   7

, , 2

    aaa bbb
jjj  10  NA
hhh   2   7

, , 3

    aaa bbb
jjj  20  NA
hhh   2   7
```

If you wanted to store operations per each character (relatively simple operations), you could take advantage of some of R's meta-programming features:

```
funcs <- c(g = '*', t = '+', d = '-')
modifiers <- c(g = 2, t = 3, d = 4)

num_array <- apply(E, 1:3, function(x) values[x])

result <- num_array
for (i in 2:dim(num_array)[3]) {
  for (j in names(values)) {
    idx <- which(E[, , 1] == j, arr.ind = T)
    row <- idx[1, 'row']
    col <- idx[1, 'col']
    result[row, col, i] <- do.call(funcs[j], args = list(result[row, col, i-1], modifiers[j]))
  }
}

, , 1

    aaa bbb
jjj   5  NA
hhh   2   7

, , 2

    aaa bbb
jjj  10  NA
hhh   5   3

, , 3

    aaa bbb
jjj  20  NA
hhh   8  -1
```

Comment: Thanks, the first part works great!

For the second part, i'm looking to just double the element 'g' in each period, instead of doubling everything in the slice. 
So in period1 g is 5, in period 2, 10, in period 3 20, as above, but t and d are unchanged.

Comment: Thanks! It works. I am too new to upvote but I will when I get more points.

Comment: p.s. is there a way to automate the indexing process, so I can have it ready beforehand to change different things? e.g. g in each period*2, t in each period+3, d in each period-4, etc.

Comment: See edit. This gets a little weird, and you're probably better off writing a little bit of redundant code rather than this more complex version, but it works.

Comment: I actually really like this, it's really simple. But I need to be able to do more complex things, such as g = (d[i-1]*t[i-2])+2*t[i].

Comment: Then you may want to post that as a new question.

Comment: Sure, thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

This task is more manageable in a list. You can use the following:

```
# Example data
D <- c('g', 't', NA, 'd')
nPeriods = 3
column.names = c('aaa', 'bbb')
row.names = c('jjj', 'hhh')
threeD.names = c(1:nPeriods)
E = array(c(D), dim=c(2, 2, nPeriods),
          dimnames = list(row.names, column.names, threeD.names))

# Convert array to list
array_list <- lapply(seq(dim(E)[3]), function(x) E[,,x])

# Re-assign values
array_converted <- lapply(array_list, function(x){
  x <- ifelse(x == "g", 5, x) # your conversion values
  x <- ifelse(x == "t", 2, x)
  x <- ifelse(x == "d", 7, x)
  x <- apply(x, 2, as.numeric) # Ensures values are numeric
  return(x)
})

# For final format as array (if you want)
final_array <- simplify2array(array_converted)
```